# Python - print link.get href - print output url only separated by commas

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to separate the url with commas,

code :

```
for link in v.find_all('a'):
    print (link.get('href'))
```

output :

```
xxxx@xxxx-K43U:~/Desktop$ python p.py
https://ecs7.tokopedia.net/img/product-1/2016/1/28/22599505/22599505_ab305ff4-e19f-489e-bcdc-113aeb7581ea.jpg
https://ecs7.tokopedia.net/img/product-1/2016/1/28/22599505/22599505_8d47964f-75af-42bc-9af8-b60e4562ae01.jpg
https://ecs7.tokopedia.net/img/product-1/2016/1/28/22599505/22599505_9cc59e50-ac85-4046-83df-ae3f53042f19.jpg
https://ecs7.tokopedia.net/img/product-1/2016/1/28/22599505/22599505_48cf7f0e-b70c-424d-8000-5ca7f842b1e3.jpg
https://ecs7.tokopedia.net/img/product-1/2016/1/28/22599505/22599505_2cce9f72-85dd-4006-a306-d7bbf83a45e4.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
print(','.join([link.get('href') for link in v.find_all('a')])
```

Note that if you want to dump the URLs into a file, you should better use the [`csv` module.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: Maybe set `href=True` so you don't try join None

Comment: how do I remove the mark (") in front and at the end, and made some columns in the CSV file. [ ", , , , ," ] . thx

Comment: @Khorud you are probably trying to write the joined string. Instead, try writing the list of links using the `writerow()`. If you experience difficulties, feel free to ask a separate question. Thanks!